# Questions on signals processing in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, signals

I would really appreciate if someone can help me find answer for below questions related to signals in linux? Did lot of searching but did not receive an answer.

1. Does a signal (eg : SIGINT) interrupt a system call(eg : read()
   ) if that system call is in progress for that process? or will it wait for system call to be completed and switch to user mode to execute signal?
2. If it was interrupted and steps in signal handler is executed, will it retry that system call (if process is still not terminated)
3. Is it possible to configure a process in such a way that if a system call is in progress, it(system call) is completed before executing signal?

Comment: All of these are answered in the [signal man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: Almost all are in the signal man page; for #3 - block all signals for most of the main loop of your program, unblock them, the re-block them.   This makes a "signal-window", during which you will receive all outstanding signals.   It is definitely an anti-pattern, but depending on how deep a hole you have already dug for yourself....